# Regex Optional char set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to validate the Name data files with following condition

- the Name contains digits 0 to 9, not all numeric
- Name can contain hyphen -,  provided that it is not the first or last
  character of the name
- Name must contain 2 character, rest char are optional

So I tried the following Regex

```
    const regExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
```

I need at least two characters, remaining are optional in the regExp
everything works fine except this `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in the last, I want to make this optional

Comment: You need this: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$/`

Comment: The "can't all be numeric" stipulation makes this a difficult regex.

Comment: `/^(?=.{2})(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: Is `2-2` a valid name? If yes, then @WiktorStribiżew has the solution.

Comment: Then a better one is requiring a letter - `/^(?=.{2})(?![^a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/`

Comment: Only possible issue I see with that one is `a--a` which I'm guessing isn't valid. Yours does correctly accept `a-a-a`.

Comment: Great, [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809084/3832970) as it looks helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using

```
/^(?=.{2})(?![^a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9iNCAm/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2})` - at least two chars
- `(?![^a-zA-Z]+$)` - the string can't have no ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ ASCII alnum chars
- `(?:[_-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of `_` or `-` followed with 1+ ASCII alnum chars
- `$` - end of string.